# Como poderia reduzir este código?

Tags: python, python-requests

```
def hello_quantum(string):
    """
    hello_quantum: cad. caracteres --> lógico
    funcao permite jogar o jogo praticamente, permite o uso das portas para manipular o tabuleiro
    com o objetivo de igualar o tabuleiro inicial ao tabuleiro introduzido

    """
    a = eval(string.replace(":",",")) # transforma o string num tuplo, onde primeiro elemento eh o tabuleiro,
                                                                    #  e segundo eh o numero jogadas maximas
    num_jogadas = a[1]
    t_objetivo = str_para_tabuleiro(str(a[0]))
    counter = 0
    t_inicial = tabuleiro_inicial()
    tabu = []

    print("Bem-vindo ao Hello Quantum!\nO seu objetivo e chegar ao tabuleiro:")
    print(tabuleiro_para_str(t_objetivo))
    print("Comecando com o tabuleiro que se segue:")
    print(tabuleiro_para_str(t_inicial))


    while num_jogadas > counter and not (t_objetivo == tabu):
        in_porta = input("Escolha uma porta para aplicar (X, Z ou H): ")

        in_lado = input("Escolha um qubit para analisar (E ou D): ")

        if in_porta == "X":
            if in_lado == "E":
                tabu = porta_x(t_inicial,"E")
            else:
                tabu = porta_x(t_inicial,"D")
            print(tabuleiro_para_str(tabu))

        elif in_porta == "Z":
            if in_lado == "E":
                tabu = porta_z(t_inicial,"E")
            else:
                tabu = porta_z(t_inicial,"D")
            print(tabuleiro_para_str((tabu)))

        elif in_porta == "H":
            if in_lado == "E":
                tabu = porta_h(t_inicial,"E")
            else:
                tabu = porta_h(t_inicial,"D")
            print(tabuleiro_para_str(tabu))

        counter += 1

    if tabuleiros_iguais(tabu,t_objetivo):
        print("Parabens, conseguiu converter o tabuleiro em %s jogadas!"%(counter))
        return True

    else:
        return False
```

Função feita com abstração de dados, por isso chama várias outras funções.

Answer (score 1):

@user133264, sua pergunta é vaga, quando pergunta como reduzir o código. Pois reduzir pode significar fazer em menos linhas, reduzir tempo de processamento, reduzir número de loops (que acaba se relacionando com os últimos dois pontos), etc.

Mas estou assumindo reduzir como fazer um código mais enxuto.

Primeiro ponto é que você não detalha as outras funções sendo chamadas, mas algo que já reduziria a quantidade de código absurdamente, seria:
1. adicionar um dicionário para mapear a relação entre `in_portas` e funções
2. checar se `in_lado` e `in_portas` receberam um valor válido 
3. trocar todos os `if`, `elif` e `else` por uma única linha de código:

```
portas = {
            'X': porta_x, 
            'H': porta_h,
            'Z': porta_z
        }
lados = ["E", "D"]

if in_porta not in portas or in_lado not in lados:
     continue

tabu = portas[in_porta](t_inicial,in_lado)
```

Acredito que aqui você já tem um grande ganho da ineficiência de loops que havia criado. Quando ao restante do código, precisaria de mais detalhes das funções para tornar ainda mais eficiente, mas me parece que você estava buscando algo para otimizar os loops mesmo (caso não, me avise)